# perl using files handles on used module

Tags: perl

I have a perl module `module.pm` and a `script.pl` file which calls the `module.pm` 
is it  possible that `module.pm` knows about files declared inside `script.pl` for example :

I have a file defination under `script.pl` something like this

```
use module;
open FILE,'>','file.txt' or die 'can\'t open file';
```

inide module.pm i want to use FILE handle for example :

```
package module

print FILE $value;
```

is it possible to do something like this and, if yes, how ?

Comment: You could create a method that would return the filehandle...

Answer (score 5):

If you use lexical filehandles instead of Barewords it is possible.

```
use module ;
open( my $filehandle , '>' , 'output.txt' ) or die 'Cannot open.' ;
module::some_fun( $filehandle ) ;
```

and in `module.pm`

```
package module ;
sub some_fun {
  my ( $filehandle ) = @_ ;
  print $filehandle "Hello world.\n" ;
}
1 ;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for lexical filehandles.  They've been around for more than a decade.  Use 'em! :)

Comment: Direct filehandles can be used in the same way by passing a reference to the glob: `module::some_fun(\*FILE);`

Comment: @BradGilbert Yes, technically bareword filehandles would work as well since bareword filehandles are global. And thats why one should use lexical filehandles.

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible to do this if you don't `use strict`, but it's really bad practice.  The better option is to pass the file handle to your `module.pm` method/function(s).

```
use module;
open my $FILE,'>','file.txt' or die 'can\'t open file';

somesub($FILE);
```

Then:

```
package module;

sub somesub {
    my $FILE = shift;
    ... 
}
```

Comment: You don't even need to drop `use strict`; I'm pretty sure Exporter can do this. Though, as you said, you *shouldn't* do this.

Comment: @derobert: Maybe `strict` isn't necessary, but Exporter is for going the other direction.

Comment: Once the symbol-table entries are aliased, I don't think the direction matters. Will test to be sure...

Answer (score 3):

As Flimzy answers, you should not do this. There are better ways to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to accomplish. I'll cover some in a second.

You can open a file in a different namespace than your package—or print to one:

```
package module;
print main::FILE "some text\n";
```

alternatively, in your program:

```
open(module::FILE, '>', '/tmp/file');
```

You could use `caller` to find the caller's package (instead of just assuming main). That way, you could always use the caller's FILE.

## Better ways

### Anonymous filehandles stored in variables

You really should be using globs stored in scalars nowadays. In other words, your open call should look like this:

```
open my $file, '>', '/tmp/file'
```

Then `$file` is an ordinary scalar, and you can pass it around like you would any other variable. So, maybe you'd have this code in your module:

```
package module;
sub foo {
    my $dest = shift;
    print $dest "hello, world\n";
}
1;
```

And then in your program, after that open, you'd call `module::foo($file)`.

### Anonymous filehandles and OO

If you have a bunch of routines in module that all take the same output filehandle, it can get tedious to pass it around all the time. Instead, create an object:

```
package module;
use Moose;

has output_fh => (
    is => 'rw',
    required => 1,
);

sub foo {
    my $self = shift;
    print $self->output_fh "hello, world\n";
}
```

Then, in your non-module code, you do something like this:

```
open my $fh, … ;
my $obj = module->new(output_fh => $fh);
$obj->foo();
```

the advantage of this approach grows as you start to carry around more state in `$obj`.

### Anonymous filehandles and localized package variables

If you don't want to go the OO approach (which is generally cleaner than this approach) you can do this in your module:

```
package module;
our $OUTPUT_FH = undef; # or sensible default

sub foo {
    print $OUTPUT_FH "hello, world\n";
}
```

and then in your non-module code:

```
open my $fh, … ;
local $module::OUTPUT_FH = $fh;

module::foo();
```

The `local`-ization will make sure that when your current block exits, the previous value of `$module::OUTPUT_FH` is restored. This will make subroutine calls work (without trampling each other's settings) *as long as* each subroutine that changes it localizes it first.

### If you must work with pre-5.6 perl:

Perl 5.6 (released 2000-03-22, almost 12 years ago) introduced filehandle autovivification that makes that `open my $fh, …` line work. In earlier versions, you need to make the glob yourself. The `Symbol` module provides an easy way:

```
use Symbol qw(gensym ungensym);
my $fh = gensym; # not sure if pre-5.6 had geniosym; if so, use that instead
open $fh, …
⋮
close $fh;
ungensym $fh;
```

If you want to go before perl 5, which became stable in 1995, then you're on your own.